# matching complete word using replace in php

Tags: php, html, css, regex, replace

I am using **replace** function in PHP to replace and underline word,

```
  $replace='<span style="font-weight:bold; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;" >'.$term.'</span>';
  $post = str_ireplace($term, $replace, $post,$count);
```

The problem is that if the matching word is `are` and the subject is `care`, It just underline `are` and not `c`, any other way to do that so that it should underline the whole word.

Comment: Use `preg_replace()` instead of `str_ireplace()` so you can match word boundaries.

Comment: @Barmar so that will underline whole word? how

Comment: You actually want to match the word `care` when the term is just `are`? I assumed you didn't want it to match at all.

Comment: You should use a class instead of inline css, that will make it easier to manage in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$replace='<span style="font-weight:bold; border-bottom: 1px solid #999999;" >$0</span>';
$post = preg_replace("/[a-z]*{$term}[a-z]*/i", $replace, $post);
```

`[a-z]*` matches any sequence of letters, so this will include the rest of the word around the matching term in the match. `$1` in `$replace` is substituted with whatever matched the regular expression.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/XNxGaz)

Comment: I've added a link to a demo at IDEone.com.

Comment: There was more than 10 minutes between the downvote and edit, so I don't think they're the same person. I sure hope someone wouldn't downvote just because of a little typo.

Comment: @JoshC: I didn't downvote. If you look at the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20005783/revisions), you can see that there was a syntax error and I was merely correcting that.